# Magento customer_register_success Observer, get referral page

Tags: magento, registration, referrer

I have an observer in Magento that fires whenever the customer registers a new account. What I would like to do is find out if that registration came from checkout, or from the normal registration page. What can I call from the observer to find which page the registration referral came from internally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the last X pageviews in magento registry by putting something like this into some PHP code which is executed each time.

```
$urlHistory = (array) Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMyUrlHistory();
while (is_array($urlHistory) && count($urlHistory) > 3) {
    array_shift($urlHistory);   
}
$urlHistory[] = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setMyUrlHistory($urlHistory);
```

You can then analyse `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMyUrlHistory()` within your observer.

Comment: I thought about setting a session variable or cookie value when one of the two pages are visited, but I didn't see cluttering the cookies as a logical approach, so sessions seem the way to go. Curious question though, from your sample code, I don't see the function `getMyUrlHistory` in `Mage_Core_Model_Session` or any of it's parents for that matter (the model extends Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract, Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien, and Varien_Object). Are you using a rewrite or core override?

Comment: Keyword "magic methods". Magento uses magic setters and getters a lot.

Comment: Hmm, interesting read, didn't know Magento implemented that part of PHP.